# MongoDB - How to group by two fields & sum values of a field?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have array json like this & how to group on **itemId** and **different date** :

```
let data=[
           {itemId:'001', tranDate:'2020/03/15', qty:10},
           {itemId:'001', tranDate:'2020/03/15', qty:30},
           {itemId:'002', tranDate:'2020/03/15', qty:20},
           {itemId:'001', tranDate:'2020/03/16', qty:50},
         ]
```

I want result like image below :

[image: Require output]

Please help me on this.

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried till now ?

Comment: I try with aggregate but work wrong please show me

Comment: @whoami that's ok :) thank you

Comment: it is just give me some tip for what i want :) @whoami

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB's aggregation to do this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** group on itemId & tranDate & sum qty field values */
  {
    $group: { _id: { itemId: "$itemId", k: "$tranDate" }, v: { $sum: "$qty" } }
  },
  /** Push entire data into data field [{k :k...,v:v...},{k :k...,v:v...}] */
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {
        $arrayToObject: [
          [
            { k: "$_id.k", v: "$v" },
            { k: "itemId", v: "$_id.itemId" }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  /** Replace data as new root for each document */
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5D5ZPwfvGTa)

**Ref :** [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) , [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) , [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) , [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html)